# How match in C# with Regex Class the string which I partially know?

Tags: c#, regex, match

I am currently trying to use the Regex Class to match a value in the string that I partially know.

I'm sure this value will be unique in the string but I don't know all the characters.

For example: I'm looking for "shi" with the first two characters which can be [a-zA-Z0-9], but I don't understand how set

```
Regex regex = new Regex();
```

for finding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Regex regex= new Regex(@"\w{2}shi");
```

@ - "\" is not escape

\w - is an alphanumeric word

{2} - two chars

shi -  shi

This matches `xxshi`, `00shi`, `WWshi`, `aBshi`, `0ashi`, `Z4shi`...

Comment: @EIRU. this solution has some problems, like "xadashi" matches too, etc... And don't forget to accept the answer if you found it useful and works.